# How can I get this Linq-To-Sql query to work in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

So I have been trying to convert my L2S code to EF 4.1, mostly because L2S has become annoyingly hard to do schema updates for.  It unfortunately seems like EF's linq capabilities are extremely lacking, and I am unsure of how to write this query in EF, as it seems like you cannot do date arithmetic in EF.  My Linq-To-Sql code is:

```
// Check for any scheduled requests that have not started within the last 24 hours since the scheduled time on the previous day
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
req = _context.TestRequests.Where(x => x.scheduled_time != null 
        && x.TestRequestRuns.Count > 0

        // Make sure the current time is after the request's scheduled time
        && DateTime.Now > (currentDate + x.scheduled_time.Value)

        //  Check to see if the scheduled time today is later than the last test run start time, if so start a test run
        && (currentDate + x.scheduled_time.Value) > 
            x.TestRequestRuns.Where(y => !y.reran)
                             .OrderByDescending(y => y.start_dt)
                             .First().start_dt)
     .OrderBy(x => x.scheduled_time)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is for a system to run automated tests at scheduled times on a daily basis.  The basic idea behind this query is I am retrieving test requests that has been run at least once, that have a scheduled time of prior to right now, and test requests that have not been run since the last scheduled time.

This query works perfectly with `_context` is hooked up to the L2S data context, but when used against my EF 4.1 `DbContext` I get an `ArgumentException` with the message `DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.`.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work and how I can fix this for EF 4.1?

**Edit**:

To be more specific, EF seems incapable of performing Date Arithmetic and `(currentDate + x.scheduled_time.Value)` is what is causing the exception.

Comment: What is the data time of scheduled_time?

Comment: scheduled_time is a `TimeSpan?` in the POCO (for CodeFirst) and a time(7) in MSSql

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the data type of the `scheduled_time` field, I would suspect the errant lines are the two where you attempt the calculation:

```
currentDate + x.scheduled_time.Value
```

I would imagine that you are attempting to add a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` object, which gives a sort of type mismatch in EF4.1. Why don't you call [.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx) on `currentDate` and see if this works a bit better:

```
currentDate.Add(x.scheduled_time.Value)
```

Comment: `scheduled_time` is a DateTime field in the POCO class, and is a `Time(7)` field in the database

Comment: @Kall: In that case, you should be aware that a `Time(7)` doesn't convert to a `DateTime` member in auto-generated classes by default, but rather to a `TimeSpan` member. In such instances, you should use the `.Add()` method. Verify the member type to see if it is indeed a `TimeSpan`. I've updated my answer accordingly to utilize it if so.

Comment: My mistake, the Poco is a `TimeSpan?` not `DateTime`

Comment: @Kall: I expected that. It actually explains the `arguments must have a numeric common type` expectation from the addition operation since you're trying to add a TimeSpan to an unlike DateTime. Try the recent edit I made to the code using the Add method on the DateTime object.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work.  It exceptions with "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Add(System.TimeSpan)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."  blah

Comment: This might seem really crazy, but have you tried converting the timespan and datetime to ticks, doing the addition, then converting back to a datetime for the comparison?

Comment: Nope.  `x.scheduled_time.Value.Ticks` exceptions with "The specified type member 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Answer (score 1):

Check out, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx. They may help you when trying to do Date functions in EF. I use the DatePart stuff alot.

Comment: oooh good link!  Although those functions make things a bit harder to do.